# How to get the camera function and selecting a image from the gallery to work?

Tags: java, android, camera, gallery

Followed the steps in youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4LCnoVqQ6N4) for my first android tutorial but I couldn't get the app to work, as I am unable to execute the camera on my physical phone where it kept giving me this popup "Something went Wrong while taking photos" when I press the camera imageview.

And when I am at the gallery choosing a photo it will cause the app to suddenly stop. Thus, I downloaded the author's source code [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2rvGRbu0A83cjBBZElhdGp5OHM/view) but I also encounter the same issues stated above.

Tried adding the permission for camera,read,write storage in the androidmanifest too but without any luck of solving it. Read some camera documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-check) but was lost as to how to include it into the source code to get it to work?

Error Log after I selected an image from the gallery:

```
08-17 12:21:08.181 17286-17286/com.example.user.cameratoserver E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.user.cameratoserver, PID: 17286
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=400, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:104460 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.user.cameratoserver/com.example.user.cameratoserver.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=17286, uid=10038 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3798)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3841)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:154)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1440)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=17286, uid=10038 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
                                                                             at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1627)
                                                                             at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
                                                                             at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
                                                                             at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:427)
                                                                             at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:497)
                                                                             at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:439)
                                                                             at com.kosalgeek.android.photoutil.RealPathUtil.getDataColumn(RealPathUtil.java:131)
                                                                             at com.kosalgeek.android.photoutil.RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API19(RealPathUtil.java:62)
                                                                             at com.kosalgeek.android.photoutil.GalleryPhoto.getPath(GalleryPhoto.java:49)
                                                                             at com.example.user.cameratoserver.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:100)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6490)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3794)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3841) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1440) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Well it is in the posted LogCat lines: `reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=17286, uid=10038 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
                                                                             at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1627)`.

Comment: I added the permission already before posting this post into the androidmanifest.xml but still not solving the problem of crashing the app? That logCat line still resurface despite adding the permission to read external storage.

Comment: The app does not have to crash if you try-catch that exception.

Comment: Running for Android 6.0? Then you have to request also runtime permissions.